# MySQL SELECT query from 2 tables producing inconsistent results

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

The goal is to return an array of available users that are assigned to the site we are working on and are available to do the task we want to assign.

For this question, we can assume that we are working on site_id 4 and we are trying to assign task_id 2.

site_tasks_assignments

```
id | user_id | site_id | task_id | complete
--------------------------------------------
12 | 6       | 4       | 2       | 1
13 | 4       | 3       | 2       | 0
14 | 2       | 4       | 3       | 0
15 | 6       | 4       | 4       | 1
```

users

```
id | name    | site_id 
-----------------------
1  | bob     | 1
2  | henry   | 4
3  | jane    | 2
4  | mary    | 3
5  | kyle    | 4
6  | steve   | 4
```

Users should show up in the results if:

- The `users.site_id` is = the id of the site we're working at (again, assume `site_id` 4)

AND, any of the following are true:

- the `users.id` does not appear in the `site_task_assignments.user_id` at all, meaning they have been assigned no tasks at any sites,
- the user is in the `site_task_assignments` table but *has not* been assigned that specific task (`task_id` 2, in this case),
- the user is in the `site_task_assignments` table and *has* been assigned that specific task AND the `site_task_assignments.complete` column for that row is 1

I expect:

```
id | name    | site_id 
-----------------------
2  | henry   | 4   <- not assigned to task 2, can work on site 4
5  | kyle    | 4   <- not assigned to any tasks, can work on site 4
6  | steve   | 4   <- WAS assigned to task 2, task 2 complete, can do task 2 again, can work on site 4
```

I tried several versions of a query, some involving some sort of JOIN, and a couple with subqueries, etc.  The closest I've gotten:

```sql
SELECT u.*, sta.task_id, sta.user_id, sta.complete
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN site_task_assignments AS ci
ON u.id = sta.user_id
WHERE u.site_id = 4
AND (u.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM site_task_assignments)
    OR (u.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM site_task_assignments)
        AND sta.task_id = 2 AND complete = 1)
    OR (u.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM site_task_assignments)
        AND (sta.task_id = 2 AND complete = 1
            OR sta.task_id != 2 AND complete = 0)))
```

This gives me inconsistent results.  On some tasks, it's fine, on other tasks that have already been assigned it sometimes gives me users where they have already been assigned to a task but complete is 0.  On tasks that have not been assigned at all, it gives me duplicates of the same user if they are already in the `site_task_assignments` table for other tasks.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Please indent code reasonably per syntax & semantics. Please read about table format in the editor help. But these tables should be initialization code in columns & actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something but it seems that your three criteria can be rewritten as:

- AND `users.id` is not currently assigned to incomplete `task_id` 2

```sql
SELECT u.*, sta.task_id, sta.user_id, sta.complete
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN site_tasks_assignments AS sta
    ON u.id = sta.user_id
    AND u.site_id = sta.site_id
    AND sta.complete = 0
    AND sta.task_id = 2
WHERE u.site_id = 4
AND sta.id IS NULL;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8i20v87f).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct u.id as id,name, u.site_id as site_id 
from users u
left join site_tasks_assignments s
on u.id=s.user_id 
where u.site_id=4 and (s.user_id is null 
                        or not exists (select 1 from  site_tasks_assignments 
                                        where site_tasks_assignments.user_id=s.user_id and site_tasks_assignments.task_id =2)
                        or exists (select 1 from  site_tasks_assignments 
                                        where site_tasks_assignments.user_id=s.user_id and site_tasks_assignments.task_id =2 and complete=1)
                        )
;
```

See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iB4hSEHQwNspZ3Md9tmW69/0